# how to refresh JScrollPane.viewPort on maximizing and minimize

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jviewport

Could you please tell me how can I refresh viewPort or maximizing and minimizing the window in JScrollPane. I know I may have to called repaint or revalidate but I do not how write listener for that.

Minimize window [image]

Maximize window [image]

Comment: Typically it should be handled automatically.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content should implement `Scrollable`:

```
public boolean scrollableTracksViewportWidth() {
    return true;
}
```

This will also block horizontal scrolling.

Comment: @Ashish FYI - Understand what this change does to your component, it will keep the component at the same width as the view port.